# Convert php to java/android arrays

Tags: java, php

```
$tagArray = array(
    "apples" => 12,
    "oranges" => 38,
    "pears" => 10,
    "mangos" => 24,
    "grapes" => 18,
    "bananas" => 56,
    "watermelons" => 80,
    "lemons" => 12,
    "limes" => 12,
    "pineapples" => 15,
    "strawberries" => 20,
    "coconuts" => 43,
    "cherries" => 20,
    "raspberries" => 8,
    "peaches" => 25
    );
```

How I can do this in Java, and how to calling for the first and second params?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Java has no built in support for associative arrays. The corresponding datastructure in java is a [`Map`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). In this case you could for instance make use of a [`HashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Here's one way.

```
Map<String, Integer> tagArray = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
    put("apples", 12);
    put("oranges", 38);
    put("pears", 10);
    put("mangos", 24);
    put("grapes", 18);
    put("bananas", 56);
    put("watermelons", 80);
    put("lemons", 12);
    put("limes", 12);
    put("pineapples", 15);
    put("strawberries", 20);
    put("coconuts", 43);
    put("cherries", 20);
    put("raspberries", 8);
    put("peaches", 25);
}};
```

To get the value for, say, `"lemons"` you do

```
int value = tagArray.get("lemons");
```

As @Peter Lawrey points out in the comments: If the order in the array is important to you, you could use a `LinkedHashMap` instead of a `HashMap`.

Comment: Too fast for me. ;) I would use a LinkedHashMap to retain order as you would in an array.

Comment: Wow, java has this kind of initialization now? I'm learning! Also, (@lacas) here's some info about it: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization

Comment: Ah, right, arrays are ordered as opposed to maps... I'll update my answer.

Comment: It's just an anonymous class. No magic. But a clever trick anyway ;-)